# Saved messages can't be unsaved in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a saved message which can't be unsaved. I click the button to unsave it and it disappears, but when I next open "/saved", it's back in there. No matter how many times I unsave it, it always comes back.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this problem occuring or I am the only one?

And is there any workaround or way to fix it and unsave it - by editing xml files or registry editor or some such?

Comment: +1 I think you have found a bug. I have tested it, and I have the same issue

Comment: I have this too. But what exactly is your technical question that you want to be answered?

Comment: @Roman, I edited my question to add details - "And is there any workaround or way to fix it and unsave it - by editing xml files or registry editor or some such?"

Comment: I have just tested this and have had the same result. to clear the message I then deleted the following folders (Cache & IndexedDB) in "C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams". However I am not sure if this will have adverse effects to other items. I would like to add that I had 1 other saved message and this still existed after deleting these folders whilst the message I wanted to be removed was successfully removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log out from the Teams app to clear the session, then log in again. The unsaved message should be gone from the saved messages. It worked for me.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, so I'm accepting it :)